# iBeacon Monitoring: wait too long for didExitRegion method get called

Tags: ios, ibeacon

I am developing **iBeacon**-based **ios** Apps.

I want to let didExitRegion got fired in the background immediately when iBeacon is out the beacon region.

But I found that it takes about 20-40s seconds to fire the didExitRegion event. **I want this method fired immediately**.

I also noticed didEnterRegion event takes only a few seconds to fire.

What is controlling the delay of firing these two methods, can I adjust this delay?

Comment: It depends on beacon, some beacon take 10 to 20 secs time to turn on and off properly to be in region and not in region. And if you are using core-lotion then also it depends on location updates too.

Comment: It's working on BLE so it will take minimum 30 sec to call `didExitRegion ` method

Comment: Thanks for the kind reply. 30 sec waiting time for didExitRegion to trigger seems really long. And the few seconds for didEnterRegion to trigger is acceptable. And these delay time seems to be identical for several types of beacons I have tried. So I think this delay time maybe is decided by the IOS system rather than the hardware.  Is there any way to adjust this time even from the system?  I have taken several days to search info to figure this out, since my App heavily reply on this trigger events.